# Route Match Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I am getting an error from rails complaining about a route.

This is the link

```
link_to 'Add New Rate', new_owner_property_rate_path
```

The Error

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"owner/rates"}
```

The path looks fine as if I rake routes I am getting this route line,

```
new_owner_property_rate GET    /owner/properties/:property_id/rates/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"owner/rates"}
```

This is my route file, They sit within a folder called owner hence the namespace

```
namespace :owner do
  resources :properties do
    resources :rates
  end   
  root :to => "home#index"
end
```

The Rates Controller

```
class Owner::RatesController < Owner::BaseController

  def index
    @rates = Rate.all
  end

  def new
    @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
    @rate = Rate.new
  end
end
```

I can enter the path manually fine?

Any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. I had to add the object in the path ie,

```
new_owner_property_rate_path(@property)
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may not have reloaded the Routes correctly?  Try restarting your Rails app server.  I have seen routes fail to recognize even though the named route is loaded correctly and the route is defined.

A great trick to test named routes is to open a Rails console (./script/console) and reference on the "app" shortcut like so:

```
$> ./script/console
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.5)
>> app.new_owner_property_rate_path
NoMethodError: undefined method `new_owner_property_rate_path' for #<ActionController::Integration::Session:0x109bd1a78>
        from vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_process.rb:511:in `method_missing'
        from (irb):1
>>
```

This is the easiest way I know to validate new routes and test out a sample expression or named route.  This is especially useful for vetting parameterized routes with weird errors.

EDIT: Note, there is an object called "app" available in the Rails console which is a reference to your Rails application and lets you test out named routes and many other aspects of the application.

Comment: Sorry but I did reload the routes file and restart the server. I tried the path in the console and it gave me no routes match. I cant understand as everything looks right to me.